# Windows Phone with Json - Error reading JObject from JsonReader

Tags: c#, json, exception, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for Windows Phone, where a ListBox show data from Json file.
When my Json file have one item, my code works fine, but when more one, the exception is

> "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   object: StartArray. Path ", line1, position 1."

Json1 when works fine:

```
{"xId":"52","result":{"type":"Basico.Bean.MunicipioClass.TMunicipio","id":1,"fields":{"FRefCount":0,"FId":52,"FNome":"Sumare","FEstado":"SP","FPais":"Brasil"}}}
```

Json2 when works bad:

```
[{"xId":"52","result":{"type":"Basico.Bean.MunicipioClass.TMunicipio","id":1,"fields":{"FRefCount":0,"FId":52,"FNome":"Sumare","FEstado":"SP","FPais":"Brasil"}}},{"xId":"53","result":{"type":"Basico.Bean.MunicipioClass.TMunicipio","id":2,"fields":{"FRefCount":0,"FId":53,"FNome":"Paulinia","FEstado":"SP","FPais":"Brasil"}}}]
```

My code:

```
 public PivotPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent()
        String text;

        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("json.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, store))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        {
            try
            {
                DataContext = this;

                // Your JSON string
                string json = text;

                // Parse as JObject
                JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

                // Extract what you need, the "fields" property
                JToken jToken = jObj["result"]["fields"];

                // Convert as Fields class instance
                Fields fields = jToken.ToObject<Fields>();

                Items = new ObservableCollection<Fields>() { fields };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<Fields> Items { get; set; }

    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FId")]
        public int FId { get; set; }

        public string FNome { get; set; }
        public string FEstado { get; set; }
        public string FPais { get; set; }
    }
        private void AddProd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ListBoxx.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Fields fi = (Fields)this.ListBoxx.SelectedItem;


            ListBoxx2.Items.Add(fi);



        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um item para adicionar!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be parsing your json into array instead of object. Your best bet would be to make json consistent, i.e. always have a collection, even when you have only one item.

Then you could parse your json like:

```
JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject obj in arr.Children<JObject>())
{
...
}
```

Comment: but why the first sample works fine? I'm using object

Comment: because your first JSON is representation of an object. while the second JSON is an array of objects. Since you can have more than one object, try to have all your data presented as collection (i.e. array). If you do not have control over the JSON data you receive, then you can detect if you getting either one object or array of objects. For former you may use your existing code, for latter - you need to parse JSON as an array and iterate over the collection.